# Call a method of specific child classes

Tags: java

I have these following interfaces

```
interface Driveable{

    public void drive();

}
interface Flies{

    public void isFlying();
    public Integer fliesKmPerHour();
}
```

Abstract class

```
abstract class WarMachine{
  ...



class Vehlice extends  WarMachine implements Driveable{
     ...

class Airoplane extends WarMachine implements Driveable,Flies{
  ...
```

And i have the main class

```
 public class War 
   public ArrayList<WarMachine> warMachineArrayList;


    public War() {
        warMachineArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

But in the main class i have a method that i want to return an Airoplane with the highest fliesKmPerHour

```
public Airoplane getMaxAiroplane(){

        Airoplane airoplane = null;
        //..
    }
```

My question is how can i access the fliesKmPerHour by calling from the **warMachineArrayList**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First what we should do in these situation we should go to the Source where the `fliesKmPerHour();` method is coming from.
As we see here this method is coming from `Flies interface`

What we know here is that this method belongs to the Airoplane class so in the arrayList we should check for instance of Flies Interface and typecast elements to Flies
so then we can call the method

So with the  `if(warMachineArrayList.get(i) instanceof Flies)`{ we check for Flies instances in the `arrayList`
then we try to get the Airoplane that has the hightest speed with

```
if(((Flies)warMachineArrayList.get(i)).fliesKmPerHour() > speedKmh){
                     airoplane = (Airoplane) warMachineArrayList.get(i);
                     speedKmh = ((Flies)warMachineArrayList.get(i)).fliesKmPerHour();
```

And in the end we return an airoplane object

```
public Airoplane getMaxAiroplane(){

        Airoplane airoplane = null;
        int speedKmh = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<warMachineArrayList.size();i++){
            if(warMachineArrayList.get(i) instanceof Flies){
                if(((Flies)warMachineArrayList.get(i)).fliesKmPerHour() > speedKmh){
                     airoplane = (Airoplane) warMachineArrayList.get(i);
                     speedKmh = ((Flies)warMachineArrayList.get(i)).fliesKmPerHour();
                }
            }
        }
        return airoplane;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find instance with desired value by iteration over warMachineArrayList. Then you get some war mashine then check and cast and do what you need. Somting like that:

```
for (WarMachine warMashine : warMachineArrayList ) {
    if (warMashine  instanceof Airoplane ) {
        Airoplane airplane = (Airoplane) warMashine;
        // do with airplane anything you need
    }
}
```